# Display entire section header title in index bar of UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am trying to figure out if there is a simple way to display the entire section header title in the index bar of a table view.

At the moment I have just the first letter of the core data attribute specified in sectionNameKeyPath - pretty much just the boilerplate code.

I am thinking that i will need to create another array for sectionIndexTitlesForTableView from the fetchedResultsController.

Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following:

```
- (NSString *)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller sectionIndexTitleForSectionName:(NSString *)sectionName {
    return sectionName;
}
```